# How I can know that a Ubuntu ISO was created using a Live CD customization tool?

Tags: live-cd, iso, custom-distributions, customizer

How I can know that a Ubuntu ISO was created using a Live CD customization tool, e.g. remastersys? Or how I can know that a Ubuntu ISO was created or generated? 
Do Live CD customization tools leave things in generated ISO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest checking the SHA256 sum for the .iso you have vs the official ones.

1. Download the `SHA256SUMS` file from the respective release page here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/
2. Ensure that the iso you want to verify matches the file name of the iso you believe it could be from (one of the filenames in `SHA256SUMS`).
3. Ensure that the downloaded `SHA256SUMS` file and the iso are in the same folder.
4. Execute these commands in a terminal:

   ```
   cd <PATH TO THE FOLDER>
   sha256sum -c ./SHA256SUMS | grep OK
   ```
5. If it prints the file name then `OK`, it is an official iso otherwise it has been changed.

Comment: I totally forgot the checksum :D Please accept this one as the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know what they changed to the installer you will not know. It is totally possible to create an installer with alterations you never ever going to notice.

If you want to be sure that you download an official unaltered version of Ubuntu you need to get the file from the official source. The would be from [this location](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) or [this location](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/) (where the last one will change the last part of the URL when we change release).

---

If you want to know more about creating an ISO or want to know how to do it to understand it start here [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679) I used that topic to create a rather large answer creating a new ISO by doing it manually. There are more good answers in there worth reading.

Comment: Many people are creating ubuntu ISO and calling it new OS. They are also calling themselves linux experts and they are also making people fool. I want to uncover what they have done by know what they have used in creating ubuntu ISO?

Comment: Start here http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd/49679#49679 I used that topic to create a rather large answer creating a new ISO by doing it manually. There are more good answers in there worth reading.

Comment: I just want to know how xyz ubuntu iso was created / generated? where to look into the ISO for what for knowing how ISO was created?

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible. Well -if- the creator left traces you might but in general nobody does that. The link above does not leave a trace in the ISO that shows you I manually created it.

Comment: live iso customization tools don't leave traces in ISO file? for example: remastersys, reconstructor, ubuntu builder, etc